# Is it possible to determine if a Meteor method was called by the server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have some [Meteor methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header) and I want to secure them so that only certain users can call them from the client. However these methods are also used by the server. I am passed the userid in this.userid so I can check if the user is logged in and if they are allowed to make the call, no problem. But when I also need to call the method from the server side how do I determine that it was a server call so I can allow the method to execute. Checking that there is no this.userid to determine if its a server call allows un-authenticated users to call the method as well. I am looking for a way to determine if the method was called by the server so I can allow it and still prevent un-authenticated users from calling the method.

```
Meteor.methods({
  makeCoffee: function (time) {
    check(time, Number);
    if(calledByServer || (Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile.usertype === 'coffee dude')){
          //Makin' Coffee
    }
    else
      throw new Meteor.Error(404, "Can't find my pants");
    return "Coffee will be made at " + time;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe makeCoffee is actually a function on the server.  Client access can be controlled by wrapping it in a method that checks userId.  Server calls always go straight to the function.

Comment: True, this is the solution I will probably end up using. But I give up some advantages of meteor methods, like using this.unblock() to run multiple methods in different fibers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`this.connection` will be `null` inside a server side method if the method was not called from a client

See the [this.connection docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#method_connection).

Comment: Has anyone found a solution that will work in functions called from the method too? Right now as soon as you go into **any** function the `this.connection` will be `null` (because you are entering another JS context for `this`).

Comment: @neopostmodern Why not use the same solution we always use in Javascript? Inside the method `var methodConn = this.connection` -- then you can use `methodConn` from your callback functions.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Meteor.call can be called from server side too now:
http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call

**Original answer:**

Make it like this:

```
makeCoffee = function (time) { //code here }

Meteor.methods({
  makeCoffeeMethod: function (time) {
    if (calledByAllowedUser())
      return makeCoffee(time);
    else
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Forbidden');
  }
});
```

Now you can call it on server bypassing the authentication.